# Right way to use ABPersonViewController?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, abaddressbook

I'm pretty new to Objective-C, so I'm sorry in advance if I'm missing something you would consider obvious :)

I wrote a simple program to display the Address Book, and select a user(mimicking the iOS Contact list).

I have a basic controller:

```
@interface BasicViewController : 
UIViewController<ABPersonViewControllerDelegate>
```

The controller recieves an ABRecordRef from a previous view.
In one of my methods, I use:

```
ABPersonViewController* ctrl = [[ABPersonViewController alloc]init];

ctrl.allowsEditing = NO;
[ctrl setPersonViewDelegate:self];
[ctrl setDisplaydPerson:person];

[self setView:ctrl.view];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:ctrl animated:
YES];
```

When I get to the actual view, I get a blank screen(with the background associated with an ABPersonView).
I fiddled a bit with displayedProperties:

```
ctrl.displayedProperties = [NSArray arraywithObjects:
     [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonLastNameProperty],nil];
```

When I specified that I only wanted to see the last name - a message appeared
on the same view - NO_VALUE_UNKNOWN

I checked in debug, and my ABRecordRef isn't null, and contains all of the relevant strings.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it :)
I called a method containing the code displayed above from a segue.
the viewDidLoad method of the super wasn't called until after my method was.

when I rearranged the calling order, it worked like a charm :)